# What does ${} mean in php?

Tags: php, oop

I get PHP file(class) from internet and on the file doc said include file like this:

```
${(require_once('file.php'))}->FunctionName();
```

i just need to know what mean of "`${}`" in this line

Comment: PHP will evaluate everything inside the `{}`, cast it as a string, then use that string as a variable name.

Comment: `NunctionName()`? I think you meant `FunctionName`, *right*?

Comment: yes,FunctionName is right.thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is evaluating the contents of `file.php` and returning it as a string

For example - if `file.php` contained "test" - then it will be end up being

```
$test->FunctionName();
```

But this just seems like very bad code... evaluating a file, and including it as a variable is just going to end in tears...